# Use Date Formatter iOS10 Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to use Date Formatter in ios 10 swift 3?
i

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You'll need two formats: one to convert your input String to a Date instance, then another to convert your Date to a String with the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to first convert the string to a date and then to a string in your required format. You can use `DateFormatter` to do this. Check the below code

```
    let date = "07-11-2016 12:00:00"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let convertedDate = formatter.date(from: date)
    formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy h a"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
    print(dateString)  // Output will be 7 November 2016 12 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "07-11-2016 12:00:00")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy HH a"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

dateString will be you desired output format of you date.

or you can simply create an extension of Date or string that return you the formatted date.